# Menu divider is not occupying full height of the menu

Tags: css

I have a menu and I want to have a vertical divider between Item 2 and Item 3. But Im not having success doing this because the divider is not occupying the full height of the menu and the menu items are not staying vertical aligned with the divider.

Also if you know how to have the logo aligned vertically with the menu items it would be nice because it is also not staying, the menu it's a bit more above the logo.

Menu html:

```
<header class="header container">
    <div class="content">
        <h1 class="main_logo fl-left"><a href="">LOGO</a></h1>
        <ul class="nav fl-right">
            <li><a href="">Item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Item 2</a></li>
            <li class="separator"></li>
            <li><a href="">Item 3</a></li>
            <li><a  class="btn" href="">Item 4</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</header>
<div class="container">
    <section class="section">Test</section>
</div>
```

The working example is here: https://jsfiddle.net/5rjdofu7/

Comment: It is caused by the `padding` value...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `line-height` to align the stuffs. So, adding the following CSS will make the logo and `<ul>` align middle vertically. Also, you have too much padding, which if you don't need, you have to get rid of.

```css
h1, ul {
  line-height: 100px;
}
```

**Preview**

If this is what you are expecting:

[image: preview]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it is a space below the divider. Do you know how to have the divider without that space?

Comment: @Jone Actually I told that in the answer. It is because of the padding... Just get rid of the `padding: 20px` for the `.content` and you will be alright.

Comment: But when i remove the padding there is still a space, the difference is that its a little smaller.

Comment: @Jone Which exact place are you referring to? The space below and above Logo? If that's the case, just change the `line-height` to be something smaller value.

Comment: @Jone Below the red divider, there's just test. I don't understand now what do you mean?

Comment: Thanks. The .header has a border bottom red, and I want that the red divider stays close to this border bottom red without any space.

Comment: @Jone Make the `line-height` to `85px`. Do you want [**this?**](https://i.imgur.com/YEEAdJh.png) - **https://jsfiddle.net/utvcyn7r/**